# RESTlet redirect sending browser riap URI

Tags: restlet

I'm using RESTlet to handle PUT requests from a browser and after a successful PUT, I want to redirect the browser to different web page.

Seems like a standard PUT->REDIRECT->GET to me, but I'm not figuring out how to do it in my RESTlet resource.

Here is my code after the PUT has done the requested work:

```
getResponse().redirectSeeOther("/account");
```

However that results in the browser getting:

```
Response Headers
Location    riap://application/account
```

Of course, "riap" protocol is meaningless to the browser and "application" is not a server name.  It seems like there ought to be a way to send a redirect back to the browser without building the entire URL in my redirectSeeOther() call.  Building the URL seems like to could be error prone.

Is there an easy way to redirect without building the whole URL from the ground up?

Thanks!

Sincerely,

Stephen McCants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not 100% sure in what type of class you are trying to do this.

Try :

```
Reference reference = getRequest().getRootRef().clone().addSegment("account");
redirectSeeOther(reference);
```

I usually also then set the body as

```
return new ReferenceList(Arrays.asList(reference)).getTextRepresentation();
```

but that may not be necessary for all clients, or at all.  I will usually use this style in a class that extends ServerResource - Restlet (2.0.x or 2.1.x).

Comment: Hi Caleryn, I ended up with something similar:


`getResponse().redirectSeeOther(getRequest().getHostRef()+"/account");`


However, I figured out that wasn't going to work for my specific needs as it was a response to an AJAX call, so I ended up putting the redirect in the Javascript.


Thanks for your help!